# Middleman - Import source files from an external git

Tags: ruby, git, middleman

I just started using Middleman and I love it! unfortunately my needs are a little different from the stock configuration and I couldn't find any Middleman extensions to help with this so I thought maybe there's a simpler solution before I start writing my own extension.

Here's the scenario:
Most of my source files (like templates, js and css) are stored within the source directory but the real textual content is in another git repository.
Basically I want Middleman to fetch these files before build and integrate them as regular source files for the static site.

I figured I can make this work by running something like `git clone` on a before-build hook and then copy the needed files to the source directory.

Can anyone maybe suggest an extension that's already doing it? or a configuration option I can set in middleman to get the same behavior?

Thank's

Comment: Can you explain, why you want your textual resources only be integrated within the build process? How do you develop without them?

Comment: I have a base template and style but the actual content in page come from markdown files in a remote git repo

Comment: I do something really similar. I have a CMS written in Rails, meant to allow editorial people to input content. It has a build step that clones a repository containing a Middleman project (with templates and UI features developed by a front-end dev), merges content into the localization files, and then kicks off the Middleman build process. It's a bit elaborate, and it feels a little bit hacky, but it's working fine for now.